# Spring refresh entity if db state has changed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have got a Springboot Application and a Oracle DB with lots of PL/SQL Procedures and these change the state of the DB all the Time.
So now I want to change a loaded entity an want to save it. If the entitystate of the entitymanager and the state of the db is equal everything works fine. But in some cases they are not equal. So if I load an entity and make some changes an druring this a PL/SQL Procedure changes the DB Table. If I save the Entity I will get an Execption of course. So I tried  to catch the Exception and then in the catch block I want to refresh the Entity before saving it. But I still get an Exception. Is the Transaction not jet finished? How can I handle this Problem?
I hope the example code explains a little bit.

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/*")
    public class FacadeController {

     ...

     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
     @RequestMapping( value= "/test4" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public String test4(){

        Unit unit = unitSvice.loadUnit(346497519L);   

        List<UnitEntry> entries = unit.getEntries();      

        for (UnitEntry g : entries) {
          if (g.getUnitEntryId == 993610345L) {
            g.setTag("AA");
            g.setVersion(g.getVersion() + 1);
            g.setstatus("SaveOrUpdate");
          }
        }    

        //<-- DB Table changed entity managed by entitymanger and DB Table 
        //    are no langer equal. 

        try {      
         unitSvice.updateUnit(unit , false);
        }catch(DataAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
         unitSvice.updateUnit(unit , true);
        }

       ...

     }
   }


@Service("unitSvice")
public class UnitSvice {

  @Autowired
  private UnitDao repoUnit;

  @Transactional
  public Unit loadUnit(Long _id) {
    Unit unit = repoUnit.findOne(_id);   
    return unit;
  }

  @Transactional
  public void updateUnit(Unit unit, boolean _withrefrsh )  {
   if(_withrefrsh) {
     getEntityManager().refresh(unit.getId());
   }
    repoUnit.save(unit);
  }

}
```

I hope, anyone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give trace of what kind of error you have.

Answer (score 0):

yes the problem is ..when you call load all method which is transactional method where entities became detached from session/entitymanager when you are returning from that method.. so,next you are trying to persist detached object. That's why you get exception. 
so probably you can use session.update() or session.merge() to save the new update into database.

Comment: Thanks for the response. session.update() and also refresh of the entityManager don't work. But entityManager.find(Unit.class, id) worked. The find method returns the updated db entity. So I merge and save them. It seems to work but I am not shure if this is a good practice.